# Remove close (in time) rows from the table

Tags: sql, time

I have an SQL table Tb like:

```
ID      EventDate
18179   2014-11-12 10:18:08.0
18179   2014-12-12 09:41:02.0
18179   2014-12-12 10:26:03.0
18179   2014-12-12 10:28:00.0
18179   2014-12-12 11:17:36.0
18179   2014-12-12 12:17:45.0
18179   2014-12-12 12:17:56.0
262070  2014-11-12 11:30:00.0
262070  2014-11-12 11:33:26.0
262070  2014-12-12 10:17:19.0
262070  2014-12-12 11:33:26.0
```

I need to do a grid removing for every ID: create new table by removing those rows from Tb that laid within an hour starting from the most recent.
In that particular case my table Tb_new should looks like

```
ID      EventDate
18179   2014-11-12 10:18:08.0
18179   2014-12-12 09:41:02.0
18179   2014-12-12 11:17:36.0
18179   2014-12-12 12:17:56.0
262070  2014-11-12 11:33:26.0
262070  2014-12-12 10:17:19.0
262070  2014-12-12 11:33:26.0
```

Original table is huge (millions or rows, 100K+ of ID's).
Can somebody, please, help me to find the fastest way to do it on SQL?

Comment: what RDBMS are you using? (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server etc.)

Comment: It should be compatible with SQL 2008 standart. No stored procedures allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like homework, but here's how I'd do it.

First, find all the `EventDates` that *don't* have another event with the same ID in the previous hour:

```
select *
from #Tb anchor
where not exists (
    select 1
    from #Tb base
    where base.ID = anchor.ID
        and base.EventDate < anchor.EventDate
        and base.EventDate >= dateadd(hh,-1,anchor.EventDate)
    );
```

These are your **anchor events**, for lack of a better term.  You know for a fact that you want to keep these events.  Anchor events are **known good**.

Now, delete any event that happens less than an hour after an anchor event:

```
delete invalid
from #Tb invalid
where exists (
    select 1
    from #Tb anchor
    where not exists (
        select 1
        from #Tb base
        where base.ID = anchor.ID
            and base.EventDate < anchor.EventDate
            and base.EventDate >= dateadd(hh,-1,anchor.EventDate)
        )
        and invalid.ID = anchor.ID
        and invalid.EventDate > anchor.EventDate
        and invalid.EventDate <= dateadd(hh,1,anchor.EventDate)
    );
```

Run this query once, and you eliminate a whole bunch of records you need to delete, which reveals new anchor events.  Keep running it until there are zero records affected.  At that point, no event has an event within the previous hour.

I'm sure there's a way to write it so that it will work in one query, but that logic escapes me.

Comment: Thank you! Can it be done without anchor? P.S. No, that's not homework, definitely)

Comment: "Anchor" is just a term I used to make it easier to understand the way I'm doing it.  The only other ways I can think to do it would be: 1) Use a cursor and loop through the entire table *in order* and determines whether or not to delete the record... but that logic is kind of gross to write and probably slow. 2) Write a user-defined function that, given an `ID` and an `EventDate` determines if the given record should be deleted..